# How to make sure I use specific class feature only when provided in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, software-design

Lets say I have class that use another class as feature.

```
class city{

    void travel(){
        // if rail road travel by rail

        // if no rail road travel by foot 
    }

private:
   RailRoad rails;
};
```

When I instantiate city

case 1 :  I can have city with railroad.

case 2:   I could also have city without railroad.

I thought was use `RailRoad * rails` and use `nullptr` as flag to determine the case. I was trying to avoid this because for this I have to do new and delete.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: If you don't want to perform `new` and `delete` manually you can use smart points, like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @songyuanyao: It's still dynamic allocation that you neither need nor want.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It depends on OP's intent; or you meant we should always use `std::optional` instead of smart pointers?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Not "always" but when it's appropriate, like perhaps now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a default constructed `RailRoad` is not too expensive, you could use:

```
std::pair<bool, RailRoad> optionalRailroad;
```

as member variable with the understanding that

```
optionalRailroad.first == false
```

implies the object was created without a `RailRoad` and

```
optionalRailroad.first == true
```

implies the object was created with a `RailRoad`

Comment: I like your idea but do you think its better then using std::unique_ptr as  songyuanyao suggested?

Comment: @pokche, I find it difficult to asses the pros and cons of the two approaches since I don't know how you wish to use the class. Ideally, you should not expose the member variable. Provide functions that can be implemented using my suggestion or a smart pointer. If one seems to be a problem, you could switch the member variable to the other.

Comment: A pointer plus dynamic allocation has more overhead than a bool. You could although wrap the pair in a optional like template.

Comment: @RSahu Why did you say `. Ideally, you should not expose the member variable`. . I was planing to make  std::pair<bool, RailRoad> optionalRailroad; ` private.

Comment: @pokche, that's what I meant.

Comment: This is not optimal because then you have a default-constructed object that holds no useful state and that you don't intend to use.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::optional<RailRoad>` (or `std::optional<RailRoad>` since C++17) will give you the same semantics without dynamic allocation.

Comment: What If I am limited to c++11 is there an alternative to this? I was also thinking to using just `bool` to achieve my goal.

Comment: @rokche `boost::optional<RailRoad>`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I am also not allowed to use boost at this moment :/

Comment: @pokche: Why not?

Comment: @pokche: What sort of legal reason? The Boost licence is quite permissive.

Comment: Yeah not sure .. I just joined this group so its hard for me to tell :/

Comment: @pokche: Well you ought to find out instead of guessing